# Cannot figure out my mistake for squaring numbers

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I am new to JAVA and Net beans. This is what I have to do: Create a program that stores the square of the numbers 0, 1, 2 & 9 in an ArrayList of 10 elements.

For example, the third element which has an index of 2 should store 4.

The program should then use a loop to display each element in the array as shown below.

This is my code:

```
double[] nums  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};     
double[] squares = (nums);     
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++)     
    nums[i]= i + 1;      
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++)     
    nums[i]=nums[i] * nums[i];     
System.out.println("Squares Arraylist");    
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )     
    System.out.println ("Number: "+i+  "\t Square:" + squares[i]);
```

This is the output I get:

```
Squares Arraylist     
Number: 0    Square:1.0      
Number: 1    Square:4.0      
Number: 2    Square:9.0     
Number: 3    Square:16.0      
Number: 4    Square:25.0      
Number: 5    Square:36.0    
Number: 6    Square:49.0     
Number: 7    Square:64.0    
Number: 8    Square:81.0     
Number: 9    Square:100.0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Java 8+, you could just do `double[] squares = DoubleStream.of(nums).map(x -> x * x).toArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this loop

`for(int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )
    nums[i]= i + 1;`

because nums reference is already holding the array data as we initialized while declaring it `nums  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`

and make the array data type to int unless we need it as it occupies more memory

`int[] nums  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  int[] squares = (nums);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you prefer to correct the commented line ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )     
  //nums[i]= i + 1;   -> here you went wrong
  nums[i]= i ;
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )     
  nums[i]=nums[i] * nums[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are changing your data before squaring it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )     
  nums[i]= i + 1;
```

Don't know why you are doing this. But this is where your program is changing the values of your array list from

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 to
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

So when you square it you get the squares of the updated list, and a wrong solution. Comment out these two lines and check again, hopefully you will get the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems:

- don't use `double`, use `int`. You're dealing with small whole numbers
- don't add `1` to each element
- don't initialize array

In pseudo code:

- Declare an `int` array of size 10
- For each index of the array

  - Assign the square of the index to the element at that index

In code, Java 7:

```
int[] squares = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
    squares[i] = i * i;
```

and in Java 8:

```
int[] squares = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i-> i * i).toArray();
```

---

Note: I don't know why you're printing "ArrayList"; you don't have one. You have an array. Very different.